# C++ MFC Software request focus at startup (blink in task bar)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ software based on MFC (CDialog). When it starts it is always requesting for focus, mean it is blinking in the windows task bar.

The issue is that task bar is suppose to be set in out hide mode (because I have some other UI that are supposed to cover the full screen). But since this software always request focus, windows task bar never hide until I show and hide this piece of software...

I have other MFC softwares that do not have this behaviour but so far I cannot find out what could be the difference !

If someone had a idea that would be nice !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your code? Can you post it in your question?

Comment: This is code that I have to maintain... We don't developp with MFC anymore, but I have to keep this "old" software. So code is quite huge... any particular part that could be intresting ?

Comment: The initialization part (the code that creates then shows the main dialog box) should be enough I believe.

Comment: You will find the offending code by doing a search over all files for `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I have to clean up me code before I can post anything, will try to do that.

Comment: @IInspectable: Just commented the only occurance of `SetForegroundWindow` in my project and still get this behaviour...

Comment: How is this application launched? Can the effect be observed when launched through explorer.exe, or cmd.exe?

Comment: Lets call this application App1. App1 is started by an other one called App0. The task of App1 is then to start a serie of other Apps... If I launch it by end it give the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am doing some progress...

If I had `ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);` just before the return of the `OnInitDialog()` function, then I don't get this behaviour anymore.

That is of course not perferct because I would like this application to be minimized and silent at startup, but when I try `ShowWindow` with other agrument I always get this flashing issue back...

Any other ideas are welcome ! Thanks.